# How can I steady the compass?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am making a compass for android and I have it working but it has one flaw. The reading on the compass is consistently changing by a couple of degrees even when the device is not moving. I know that this is due to the magnetic distortion messing with sensor but how can I make my app still responsive while the user moves yet not have so much variation displayed when the user is still. So how can I give the appearance of a more steady compass?

Answer (score 2):

You have to smooth the signal. How about displaying the average of the last N values instead of displaying the raw last value ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a compass, you'll need to low-pass filter **both** acceleration and magnetic field.

Here's an example of a low-pass filter. Not very elegant, but just to show the principle:

```
float filteredValue;

void lowPassFilter(float rawValue) {

    final float alpha = 0.8f;
    float filteredValue = alpha * filteredValue + (1.0f - alpha) * rawValue;

    return filteredValue;
}
```

Note that *filteredValue* is remembered after each call (like a member variable).

On the other hand, *rawValue* is the value from the sensor event, like *event.values[0]*.

Notice how every 'fresh' new *rawValue* only affects 20% of the filtered value (that's given by *alpha*). This brings 'stability' to the reading, at the cost of a delay.